# Large Gridview 1100/1100 on android

Tags: android, gridview, bitmap, large-data

I have to show 64/64 bitmaps in a grid of 1100/1100 but the scrolling is not smooth. What is the optimum way in displaying such ammount of image data?

Answer (score 0):

This is just too much memory consumption for an android app.. I don't think you really want to load all of those at the same time. I would rethink the requirements first.

There should be a solution that still satisfies the user and does not load that many views into memory. I don't know what is the use-case here, but I would suggest implementing something like paging. Load a limited amount of items, and only if user wants to see more, then show progress bar and load more.

E.g. you can load more if user scrolls to the last item, or just create a button like "Show more". I'm not sure which solution will be okay for your app. Also, I would actually load new items into the same `GridView` replacing previously loaded bitmaps, because each of them requires a lot of memory. You can always control the scrolling position programmatically if needed.